# Error to create a systemd service, with live socket

Tags: sockets, systemd

I'm trying to create a systemd service on CentOS 7.5, to acces livestatos from remote thru

File `proxy-to-livestatus.service`:

```
[Unit]
Requires=naemon.service
After=naemon.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-socket-proxyd /run/naemon/live
```

File `proxy-to-livestatus.socket`:

```
[Unit]
StopWhenUnneeded=true
[Socket]
ListenStream=6557
```

Status:

```
systemctl status proxy-to-livestatus.service 
● proxy-to-livestatus.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/proxy-to-livestatus.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mié 2018-07-18 09:11:58 CEST; 15s ago
  Process: 3203 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-socket-proxyd /run/naemon/live (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3203 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

jul 18 09:11:58 chuwi systemd[1]: Started proxy-to-livestatus.service.
jul 18 09:11:58 chuwi systemd[1]: Starting proxy-to-livestatus.service...
jul 18 09:11:58 chuwi systemd-socket-proxyd[3203]: Didn't get any sockets passed in.
jul 18 09:11:58 chuwi systemd[1]: proxy-to-livestatus.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
jul 18 09:11:58 chuwi systemd[1]: Unit proxy-to-livestatus.service entered failed state.
jul 18 09:11:58 chuwi systemd[1]: proxy-to-livestatus.service failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi to resolve this issue, we haver to enable the socket with --now option

systemctl enable --now proxy-to-livestatus.socket

and the start the proxy-to-livestatus.service

systemctl start systemctl enable --now proxy-to-livestatus.socket

Regards